# Put elements in a new bootstrap row after n number - foreach loop

Tags: php

I have an array of objects in which I want to iterate them in a foreach loop. However I want to only allow for 3 of them to be in a row and then after the 3rd, a new row to start, and so on.

```
function displayIncomeDetails($deets) {
        $result = NULL;

        if($deets != NULL) {
            foreach($deets as $deet) {
                $result .= '
                    <div class="row mt-4">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            '.$deet.'
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ';
            }
        } else {
            $result = '
                <div class="row">
                    <p style="margin: 0 auto;" class="mt-4 text-danger">No Details Found</p>
                </div>
            ';
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

So instead of 1 column in the row I would like 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`array_chunk`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.array-chunk.php) is very usable here, e.g.:

```
foreach (array_chunk($deets, 3) as $perRow) {
    $result .= '<div class="row mt-4">';

    foreach ($perRow as $deet) {
        $result .= '<div class="col-sm-3">' . $deet . '</div>';
    }

    $result .= '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know this existed

Comment: Just one more thing, how can I use this to display the keys, as it is an associative array. So if I do `($perRow as $key => $deet)` and echo the key it shows 0,1,2 etc instead of the name of the keys "One", "Two" etc

Comment: Never mind I checked the documentation and see there is a third "preserve keys" parameter, setting that to true fixed it